# JavaScript Requires and Exports in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I am writing a Node.JS REST API using Express, and I was a little confused about the `require()` and `exports` statements in Node.JS.

For instance, let's say I am writing a simple app wherein `app.js` contains the basic `app.get` statements, `routes.js` contains the functions passed as a callback to those `app.get` statements and `events.js` contains the Mongoose Schemas and Models.

Now, if `routes.js` requires `events.js`, can I call Model.find() and functions like those in `routes.js` and if yes, what exports will I have to make from `events.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to export anything from model. Just require it.

In routes.js, you can access your model using mongoose.model('Schema')

routes.js

```
require('./events.js')

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Model = mongoose.model('myModel')
```